# Can I access the static variables of the 'Class' Object?

Tags: java, class

Having this method:

```
readAllTypes(Class clazz) {...}
```

Can I access the static variables of the class?

Comment: Warning: you are using the raw type `Class`, which expect a type argument. **Never use raw types.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Just use `Class.getDeclaredFields()` (or `Class.getDeclaredField(String)`) as normal, and to get the values, use the `Field.getXyz()` methods, passing in `null` for the `obj` parameter.

Sample code:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class Foo {
    public static int bar;
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {

        Field field = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("bar");
        System.out.println(field.getInt(null)); // 0
        Foo.bar = 10;
        System.out.println(field.getInt(null)); // 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the field using [`clazz.getDeclaredFields()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()), which returns a [`Field[]`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html), or by directly getting the field by name, with [`clazz.getDeclaredField("myFieldName")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)). This may throw a `NoSuchFieldException`.

Once you've done that, you can get the value of the field with `field.get(null)` if the field represents an object, or with `field.getInt(null)`, `field.getDouble(null)`, etc. if it's a primitive. To check the type of the field, use the `getType` or `getGenericType`. These may throw an `IllegalAccessException` if they're not public, in which case you can use `field.setAccessible(true)` first. You can also set the fields in the same way if you just replace "get" with "set".